# Get current page of pagination in view and manually set count of page

Tags: python, django, pagination

1. I need to manually set count of page for pagination in view.py
2. I need to get number of current page for processing it in function.
   I next view.py:

   ```
   class VideoListView(ListView):
       template_name = "video/list.html"
       context_object_name = 'videos'
       paginate_by = 12
       request = requests.get(settings.YOUTUBE_VIDEO_COUNT_URL)
       count = simplejson.loads(request.text)['data']['totalItems']

       def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
           request = requests.get(settings.YOUTUBE_VIDEO_URL)
           data_about = simplejson.loads(request.text)
           video_list = []
           for item in data_about['data']['items']:
               video_list.append(item)
           return video_list
   ```

Count of pages must be: count/paginate_by, and on every page request json will be different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Django pagination is stored via **GET**, so in your *ListView* you need to access:

```
# This will assume, if no page selected, it is on the first page
actual_page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
if actual_page:
    print actual_page
```

so in your list view code, depends on where you need it, but if you need it in your *get_queryset* function, you can access the **request** using **self**:

```
class VideoListView(ListView):
    # ..... your fields

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        # ... Your code ...
        actual_page = self.request.GET.get('page', 1)
        if actual_page:
            print actual_page
        # ... Your code ...
```

Custom pagination object using Django Pagination:

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

def CreatePagination(request, obj_list):
    # Create the pagination
    RESULTS_PER_PAGE = 10
    paginator = Paginator(obj_list, RESULTS_PER_PAGE)
    page = request.GET.get('page')  # Actual page
    try:
        page_list = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        page_list = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        page_list = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return page_list
```

To use this `CreatePagination` function you need to pass it the request and the object list. The request is used to get the actual page, and the object list is used to generate the pagination.

This function will return a pagination that you can manage in the template the same way you're managing the automatic generated pagination from the `ListView`

Comment: Thanks, so can i manually set count of pages for pagination in view?

Comment: If you want to customize the pagination, I recommend you to check [Django Pagination](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/pagination/#module-django.core.paginator) because is more customizable, you can pass there a QuerySet and it will create a custom pagination, but yes, You can change the actual page in your python code. I will add a custom pagination using the Django Pagination in my answer